# Android 11: How to know if permission is "While using this app" or "Only this time"?

Tags: android, android-11

My app must have Camera and Audio access without being requested each time (I don't want to get into details, but trust me on this one).

Is there a way to know on Android 11+ if the user clicked "Only this time" on either Camera or Audio permission?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot say, when the user will disable the permissions given to your app.

If you want to have the permissions always (*irrespective of when you actually gonna need it*), ask the user to give the permission at the launch of your app. Other than this, you cannot stop the user to disable the permissions later.

Kind of like:

```
if (isPermissionGiven){
    //Permission given, continue...
} else {
    //Permisson not given, ask for permission...
}
```

By this you would be able to do your work unless you are doing any work to access the user's camera in background without the **user's consent** which is not **Legitimate**.